# How to convert a ttf file to fnt and how to use it in CCLabelBMFont?

Tags: fonts, cocos2d-iphone

I have a .tff file of a font. But as far as I know CCLabelBMFont only supports .fnt font files.

How do I convert the .tff file to a .fnt file? (a free option would be great)

And how do I use CCLabelBMFont? With the newly created font?

Edit:

Except "Hiero".

Comment: https://ttf2fnt.com/ is an online option.